# Generate PDF / XLSX files as attachments to REST API

Tags: spring-boot, content-negotiation

Requirement is to generate pdf / excel document on hitting the REST API endpoint.
i.e. localhost:8080/download.xlsx -> generates a file with data in .xlsx format
localhost:8080/download.pdf -> generates a file with data in .pdf format

Spring Boot version - 2.0.2

As i am using Spring Boot's relatively newer version i have to implement WebMvcConfigurer instead of extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

I am configuring the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer 
 configurer) {
    configurer
            .favorPathExtension(true)
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager 
    manager) {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new 
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    // Define all possible view resolvers
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();

    resolvers.add(excelViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(pdfViewResolver());

    resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver excelViewResolver() {
    return new ExcelViewResolver();
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver pdfViewResolver() {
    return new PdfViewResolver();
}
```

And in my controller:-

```
  @Controller
  public class MyController{

  @PostMapping(value = "/download", produces = {"application/pdf", 
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"})
public String downloadData(Model model, @RequestBody 
someRequestView requestView) {
    getSpringVersion();
    model.addAttribute("someResultList", 
    someService.extractDataForDownload(requestView));
    return "";
}
}
```

I tried everything but when i hit localhost:8080/download.pdf -> it gives me 404 not found. Please suggest resolutions to this issue.

Comment: try adding `.ignoreAcceptHeader(true)` perhaps you sent the header and it takes preference

Answer (score 0):

ExcelViewResolver has been deprecated in latest versions. Below is the example that generates an Excel document in a simple way.

First, create an Excel generator class. Configure columns as per requirement. And retrieve the data from the DB tables.

Below is the sample excel generator class.

```
public class StateExcelGenerator {

    public static ByteArrayInputStream statesToExcel(List<State> states) throws IOException {

        String[] COLUMNs = { "Id", "Name", "Desc" };

        try (Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
            CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("StateInfo");

            Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
            headerFont.setBold(true);
            headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());

            CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

            // Row for Header
            Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

            // Header
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNs.length; col++) {
                Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
                cell.setCellValue(COLUMNs[col]);
                cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
            }

            // CellStyle for Age
            CellStyle ageCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            ageCellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("#"));

            int rowIdx = 1;
            for (State state : states) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);

                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(state.getId());
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(state.getName());
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(state.getDesc());

            }

            workbook.write(out);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

        }

    }
}
```

Now Modify your controller to handle download file as shown below.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/state")
public class StateController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download/statedata.xlsx", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> excelCustomersReport() throws IOException {
    List<State> states = stateService.getData();

    ByteArrayInputStream in = StateExcelGenerator.statesToExcel(states);
    // return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=customers.xlsx");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new InputStreamResource(in));
}
}
```

Now create a hyperlink in your view page such as jsp file to access the above controller method.

```
<a href="/admin/state/download/statedata.xlsx">Click here to download the file</a>
```

Below is the downloaded excel file.

[image: Sample Excel Download File]